# SQL: Eliminate chains of duplicate in a GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I'm running a query to analyse variations in Group_member_ID for some users.
What I would like to identify is the key variations in group_member_ids (eg Group1 on 01/08/2011, Group5 on 05/08/2011).

I came up with this command:

```
select id, 
CAST(group_concat(concat('[',group_member_id,'-',from_unixtime(obs_time),']') order by obs_time) as CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8) 
from Table1 
where id=1
```

RESULT:

> imei  group/date

```
1[178-2011-06-13 18:58:31],[0-2011-06-13 19:20:56],[0-2011-06-17 17:21:57],[0-2011-06-19 16:53:29],[0-2011-06-22 16:41:11],[178-2011-09-30 16:43:11],[179-2011-10-01 18:43:11]
```

How can I eliminate the Group/date `[0-2011-06-17 17:21:57],[0-2011-06-19 16:53:29],[0-2011-06-22 16:41:11]` from this query as I already identified the first record for group_member_id=0 and the others do not matter for me...
In other words, I would like my final result to look like:

> imei  group/date

```
1[178-2011-06-13 18:58:31],[0-2011-06-13 19:20:56],[178-2011-09-30 16:43:11],[179-2011-10-01 18:43:11]
```

I'm stuck. I was thinking of using LIMIT in my group_concat but apparently it's not possible. Or is it?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: A subquery solution would best fit your needs, but you did not give a clear layout of your DB, so I can not come up with a concrete SQL for you.

Comment: there are 4 data having 0 in prefix `[0-2011-06-13 19:20:56],[0-2011-06-17 17:21:57],[0-2011-06-19 16:53:29],[0-2011-06-22 16:41:11]`. on what basis you want to delete only 3( as u mentioned in your question )

Comment: Yes, I thought so... 
Well, no need to give a clear layout as I am just selecting from 1 a single table.
There are 4 data with 0, I want to keep only the first one as it makrs the group_member_id variation (eg from 178 to 0).
Bassically, the final result should be:
1[178-2011-06-13 18:58:31],[178-2011-09-30 16:43:11],[179-2011-10-01 18:43:11]

Comment: Sorry I meant:
1[178-2011-06-13 18:58:31],[0-2011-06-13 19:20:56],[178-2011-09-30 16:43:11],[179-2011-10-01 18:43:11]

Answer (score 0):

TRY with GROUP BY

```
  SELECT id, CAST( GROUP_CONCAT ( 
                                 CONCAT('[',group_member_id,'-',from_unixtime(obs_time),']') 
                                 ORDER BY obs_time ) as CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8)
                           AS group_set  
  FROM table1 
  WHERE id=1
  GROUP BY group_member_id
```

Comment: DISTINCT won't help as the obs_time is never the same. Even if I exclude obs_time from my concat, a DISTINCT will only return the group_member_id 178 once.

Comment: then do the query step by step

Comment: Yes, I would do it for one occurence but I have obviously more rows to analyse. This is just an example.

Comment: I don't see an inner join, you meant a sub-select surely?